# Spell check on Activex Textbox stopped working

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, activex, activexobject

I have edited this question below, because I use the same bit of code for spell checking an Activex Textbox in another workbook and the code runs the spell check function every time the workbook is saved but for some reason the same code doesn't work in another workbook. Furthermore, the part of the code that provides a msgbox if a certain condition is met upon saving does work. Does anyone know why the code below is not working or why it would work in one workbook, but not another?

---

The code below is supposed to perform a spell check on an activex textbox on the excel doc before the user saves. This was working fine before and the portion of the code that checks for a condition to provide a msgbox works fine still but for some reason the spell check portion of the code has stopped working. Does anyone know why?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim xObject As Object
Dim xCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("1107").Unprotect
    Set xCell = Sheets("1107").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count)

    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each xObject In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
            xCell = xObject.Object.Text
            xCell.CheckSpelling , , , 1033
            xObject.Object.Text = xCell
        Next
    End If


If Sheets("1107").Range("c7") = "1.3.13" Then
    MsgBox "Incident report requires UoF Review"
    End If


End Sub
```

I tried changing activesheet. to sheets("1107"). to all places that had active sheets.

```
Dim xObject As Object
    Dim xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("1107").Unprotect
    Set xCell = Sheets("1107").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count)
    If Sheets("1107").OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each xObject In Sheets("1107").OLEObjects
            xCell = xObject.Object.Text
            xCell.CheckSpelling , , , 1033
            xObject.Object.Text = xCell
        Next
    End If
```

My third go got me a runtime error 1004- CheckSpelling method of Range Class failed

```
Dim xObject As Object
    Dim xCell As Range
    Sheets("1107").Unprotect
    Set xCell = Sheets("1107").Cells(Sheets("1107").Rows.Count, Sheets("1107").Columns.Count)
    If Sheets("1107").OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each xObject In Sheets("1107").OLEObjects
            xCell = xObject.Object.Text
            xCell.CheckSpelling , , , 1033 *****Error 1004 here*****
            xObject.Object.Text = xCell
        Next
    End If
```

New Variable added as recommended.

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

```
Dim xObject As Object
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim currcell As String
    Sheets("1107").Unprotect
    Set xCell = Sheets("1107").Cells(Sheets("1107").Rows.Count, Sheets("1107").Columns.Count)
    If Sheets("1107").OLEObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each xObject In Sheets("1107").OLEObjects
            currcell = xObject.Object.Text
            xCell.CheckSpelling , , , 1033
            xObject.Object.Text = xCell
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets("1107")`?

Comment: I have, but I did again after closing excel all the way out and that did not work. I updated the question to include the code with sheets("1107") used instead of activesheet.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` so you can see what error you're getting. Also you still have 2 occurences of `ActiveSheet` in there.

Comment: I got a Runtime error '1004': CheckSpelling Method of range class failed at xCell.checkSpelling ,,,1033.

Comment: Can you try using a new variable instead of `xCell`? You've already declared `xCell` as a range, then you're trying to re-assign text to it below. If `xCell` is a range, it needs a `Set`, and it can't take `Text` as a value. Just make a new variable (i.e. `Dim currcell As String`) and use that.

Comment: No, that didn't work, but I feel like I probably did it wrong. The runtime error is gone even though the On Error Resume Next is not there. Let me know if I replaced the right variable.